# What is the purpose of the directory ".java" (in jenkins home)?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

jenkins home (JENKINS_HOME) directory contains ".java" with the following contents.
What is the purpose, who creates this?

```
[jenkins@jenkins data]$ ls -R -la .java
.java:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  4 jenkins jenkins   47 Sep 24  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 32 jenkins jenkins 8192 May 26 11:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 jenkins jenkins   84 Apr 11 08:11 fonts
drwx------  3 jenkins jenkins   88 Sep 24  2021 .userPrefs

.java/fonts:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 6 jenkins jenkins   84 Apr 11 08:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 jenkins jenkins   47 Sep 24  2021 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Oct 22  2021 11.0.12
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Feb 10 08:21 11.0.13
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Mar  8 16:10 11.0.14
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Apr 11 09:28 11.0.14.1

.java/fonts/11.0.12:
total 204
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Oct 22  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 jenkins jenkins   84 Apr 11 08:11 ..
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 22  2021 fcinfo-1-040d00baa2eb-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Sep 14  2021 fcinfo-1-20ca101e47b5-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 22  2021 fcinfo-1-21c8cfa68082-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 22  2021 fcinfo-1-37affa299e53-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 22  2021 fcinfo-1-5711e7474638-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 22  2021 fcinfo-1-6b1683e97998-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Sep 14  2021 fcinfo-1-728bf3c61133-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Sep 30  2021 fcinfo-1-7b86df010aaf-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Sep 28  2021 fcinfo-1-832b491f4c04-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 22  2021 fcinfo-1-86aba7d01298-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 22  2021 fcinfo-1-8932a30d6877-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Sep 14  2021 fcinfo-1-96bd7f94e38b-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Sep 14  2021 fcinfo-1-a1583396148a-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 22  2021 fcinfo-1-a1bb55b4d274-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 13  2021 fcinfo-1-a7f7f4177010-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 22  2021 fcinfo-1-b12b7fd6f0c7-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Sep 28  2021 fcinfo-1-b1b0d9227a50-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Sep 13  2021 fcinfo-1-b503c6b64359-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct  1  2021 fcinfo-1-bc04fbd5ff6c-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 13  2021 fcinfo-1-dfeccf9ddb48-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Sep 28  2021 fcinfo-1-e3c99d9e381b-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 13  2021 fcinfo-1-e8da60a9a257-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 22  2021 fcinfo-1-eaebb37b5977-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Sep 14  2021 fcinfo-1-f32e3c0ebecd-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Oct 22  2021 fcinfo-1-f9d0aa853241-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties

.java/fonts/11.0.13:
total 172
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Feb 10 08:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 jenkins jenkins   84 Apr 11 08:11 ..
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Nov 22  2021 fcinfo-1-097221e8a108-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Feb 10 07:58 fcinfo-1-41845738ebe1-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Jan  4 12:34 fcinfo-1-46e0ccd45a88-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Nov 12  2021 fcinfo-1-474a19c2cce4-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Dec  7 09:09 fcinfo-1-614acd73e811-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Jan 31 17:36 fcinfo-1-6962f56c161d-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Dec 30 10:55 fcinfo-1-85261a0f7ec2-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Nov 26 11:35 fcinfo-1-85956c8d5f07-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Jan 27 10:22 fcinfo-1-88d1b31b3765-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Dec  7 08:50 fcinfo-1-8f030abd9c75-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Nov 24  2021 fcinfo-1-99beaa989281-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Feb 10 07:23 fcinfo-1-ace5ac3b63e6-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Feb  1 09:40 fcinfo-1-b0b039be646a-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Jan 13 09:05 fcinfo-1-b2d98a3161f6-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Nov 12  2021 fcinfo-1-c22fc2f4765b-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Dec  7 09:00 fcinfo-1-d522e357e0ae-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Jan 13 08:57 fcinfo-1-d8918f1e34ac-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Nov 19  2021 fcinfo-1-dcb3e5ad8a04-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Feb 10 07:37 fcinfo-1-f553c95bca98-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Jan 13 09:13 fcinfo-1-f9e9b7738fab-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Feb 10 08:21 fcinfo-1-facf3dc3fd74-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties

.java/fonts/11.0.14:
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Mar  8 16:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 jenkins jenkins   84 Apr 11 08:11 ..
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Mar  8 08:06 fcinfo-1-3d402af251bf-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Mar  8 08:19 fcinfo-1-4c7ea1c83a38-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Mar  8 16:10 fcinfo-1-ccb90ea5dcfc-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Mar  8 14:37 fcinfo-1-d59c3d909628-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties

.java/fonts/11.0.14.1:
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Apr 11 09:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 jenkins jenkins   84 Apr 11 08:11 ..
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Apr 11 08:16 fcinfo-1-05e5f5147559-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Apr 11 08:11 fcinfo-1-7d587d1071d0-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 7299 Apr 11 09:28 fcinfo-1-837bffc706fb-Linux-3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64-en.properties

.java/.userPrefs:
total 0
drwx------ 3 jenkins jenkins 88 Sep 24  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 jenkins jenkins 47 Sep 24  2021 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 49 Sep 24  2021 org
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins  0 Sep 24  2021 .user.lock.jenkins
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins  0 Sep 24  2021 .userRootModFile.jenkins

.java/.userPrefs/org:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  49 Sep 24  2021 .
drwx------ 3 jenkins jenkins  88 Sep 24  2021 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  47 Sep 24  2021 codehaus
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 148 Sep 24  2021 prefs.xml

.java/.userPrefs/org/codehaus:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  47 Sep 24  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  49 Sep 24  2021 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  46 Sep 24  2021 groovy
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 148 Sep 24  2021 prefs.xml

.java/.userPrefs/org/codehaus/groovy:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  46 Sep 24  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  47 Sep 24  2021 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 148 Sep 24  2021 prefs.xml
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  46 Sep 24  2021 tools

.java/.userPrefs/org/codehaus/groovy/tools:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  46 Sep 24  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  46 Sep 24  2021 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 148 Sep 24  2021 prefs.xml
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins  30 Sep 24  2021 shell

.java/.userPrefs/org/codehaus/groovy/tools/shell:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins  30 Sep 24  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  46 Sep 24  2021 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 148 Sep 24  2021 prefs.xml
```